# Magento 2 Custom Admin module giving 404

Tags: magento2.2

I have followed many tutorials but im still getting a 404 error when trying to access with a custom menu item in my module.

This is what i have, :
 registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Digital_Custom',
__DIR__
);
```

etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Digital_Custom::regenerate"
             title="Digital Custom"
             module="Digital_Custom"
             sortOrder="9999"
             action="importer/packadgeable/regenerate"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content" />

    </menu>
</config>
```

Here the new menu item is visible, but when click im getting 404

My controller Structure:

Digital
  - Custom
    - Controller
      - Adminhtml
        - Packadgeable
          - Regenerate.php
This is my controller code Regenerate.php

```
<?php
namespace Digital\Custom\Controller\Adminhtml\Custom;

class Regenerate extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context        $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) 
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Grid List page.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Grid List'));

        return $resultPage;
    }

    protected function _isAllowed() {
        return true;
        }
}
```

My route
 etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route id="regenerate" frontName="regenerate">
        <module name="Digital_Custom" before="Magento_Backend" />
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the URL isn't matching. Instead of:

```
action="importer/packadgeable/regenerate"
```

you should try:

```
action="regenerate/packadgeable/regenerate"
```

or change the route id and frontName to `importer`.

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake, got it few hours ago, thank you!

Comment: This helped me more. Thanks :)